# System.ArgumentException: There is no tracked object with id '22'. Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am using SFRichTextEditor in modal. When I try to edit the editor without the savings closing modal, then the error is showing.

C#

```
  private IJSObjectReference _richTextEditorJSObjectReference;
    _richTextEditorJSObjectReference = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/sfrichtexteditor.js");
    
    await _richTextEditorJSObjectReference.InvokeVoidAsync("Created", _id, _length);
```

JS

```
export function Created(id, inputMaxCount) {

    count = sfBlazor.RichTextEditor.getCharCount(id);
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    element.querySelectorAll(".e-rte-character-count")[0].innerText = count + " / " + inputMaxCount;
    this.CharCount(id, inputMaxCount)

    element.querySelectorAll(".e-content")[0].addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        count = sfBlazor.RichTextEditor.getCharCount(id);
        this.CharCount(id, inputMaxCount);
    });

    element.querySelectorAll(".e-content")[0].addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        this.CharCount(id, inputMaxCount)
    });
};
```

Error

> System.ArgumentException: There is no tracked object with id '22'.
> Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed.
> (Parameter 'dotNetObjectId')    at
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.GetObjectReference(Int64 dotNetObjectId)
> at
> Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvokeDotNet(JSRuntime
> jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo invocationInfo, String argsJson)
> at Ft.endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.server.js?_v=638152873680000000:1:3718)
> at Ft._invokeClientMethod (blazor.server.js?_v=638152873680000000:1:75072)
> at Ft._processIncomingData (blazor.server.js?_v=638152873680000000:1:72696)
> at Ft.connection.onreceive (blazor.server.js?_v=638152873680000000:1:67009)
> at i.onmessage (blazor.server.js?_v=638152873680000000:1:51322)

Comment: Please include some code samples.